# Hotel booking / Reservation logic

Tags: c#

I am working working on a very simple hotel booking project using Visual Studio 2013 Community for my coding class where the user can book a customer into a room and the program should stop the user if the room is already booked on that date or they overlap in some way with other bookings.

The problem I am facing is that if the user makes a new booking where the Check In and Check Out dates are the same as 2 other bookings Check Out dates, it can overlap over another booking.

Example:
Booking A - 01.01.15 to 02.01.15
Booking B - 03.01.15 to 04.01.15
Booking C - 05.01.15 to 06.01.15
Booking D - 02.01.15 to 06.01.15

In booking D the user puts 02.01.15 as the Check In and 06.01.15 as Check Out and for some reason the program does not catch it and allows the booking over B and C.

```
public override void Add(Booking booking)
    {
        // Don't allow a new booking if the room is already out.

        var currentBooking = _ctx.Bookings
            .Where(b => b.RoomId == booking.RoomId)               
            .Select(b => (booking.CheckOut > b.CheckIn && booking.CheckIn < b.CheckOut)
                      || (booking.CheckIn < b.CheckIn && booking.CheckOut > b.CheckIn)) 

            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentBooking)
        {
              throw new BookingException("The Room is already out on that date.");
        }

        _ctx.Set<Booking>().Add(booking);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I would have thought that by checking if the new Check In and Check Out were both the same as previous Check Out (see below) I would solve the problem but there must be something wrong with that logic.

```
.Select(b => (booking.CheckOut > b.CheckIn && booking.CheckIn < b.CheckOut)
          || (booking.CheckIn < b.CheckIn && booking.CheckOut > b.CheckIn)
          || (booking.CheckIn == b.CheckOut && booking.CheckOut == b.CheckOut))
```

Should I be doing something like checking if the new Check In and Check Out are the same as previous Check Out´s -1 day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two periods overlapped if start of first period is between start and end of second or if start of second period is between start and end of first, then you can write:

```
public override void Add(Booking booking)
        {
            // Don't allow a new booking if the room is already out.

            var currentBooking = _ctx.Bookings
                .Where(b => b.RoomId == booking.RoomId && 
        (booking.CheckIn <= b.CheckOut && booking.CheckIn >= b.CheckIn ||
         b.CheckIn <= booking.CheckOut && b.CheckIn >= booking.CheckIn))               
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (currentBooking != null)
            {
                  throw new BookingException("The Room is already out on that date.");
            }

            _ctx.Set<Booking>().Add(booking);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But this method can work incorrect in case when some booking saves to db in another thread after line with check

```
if(currentBooking)
```

executes.

You can create trigger on table that check constraint in database to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks Oleg!  This seems to take care of every scenario I can throw at It.
I only had to change if(currentBooking) to if (currentBooking != null) and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you need some code to check if a specific date is between 2 dates (I don't know if I'm right or not in your case)

```
> public int CheckDateBetween2Dates(DateTime Date)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 if (Date.Ticks >StartingDate.Ticks && Date.Ticks < EndDate.Ticks)
>                 {
>                     //..The Date is between the 2 dates return 1;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     //..The Date is not between them return 0;
>                 }
>             }
>             catch
>             {
>                 return -1;
>             }
> 
>         }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid overlapping

```
(!(booking.start < b.CheckOut && b.CheckIn < booking.CheckOut))
```